# iAd bannerViewActionDidFinish never called: How to know when the user closed an iAd?

Tags: ios, iad

I've searched multiple forums and looked at existing questions on stackoverflow but haven't found a solution to this.  I have a game screen where I show an iAd at the bottom of the screen.   The ad shows up correctly, and when I tap on that it expands to full screen.  However, when I click on the X button in the second screen, the ad closes WITHOUT bannerViewActionDidFinish getting called in the delegate.

I really need a way to know when the ad closed so I can relayout my screen accordingly.  Any ideas?

Update: Added all my view controller code related to iAd below.  I have added the AdBannerView via Interface Builder, and linked it to self.mAdBannerView as an outlet.  There's nothing special I am doing in the view controller.  And one more point: I haven't posted by app to the iTunes Store yet, so I am getting test Ads from Apple "You're Connected to iAd" and I've tried both on the emulator and a device - same result and same issue.

Note that the callbacks for bannerViewDidLoadAd and didFailToReceiveAdWithError ARE being called, as expected.

Here's my code sample:

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"bannerViewActionDidFinish"); //this is never called
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.mAdBannerView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Could you provide all of your iAd code please?

Comment: Hi Daniel, added the rest of the code too.

Comment: Sorry @Gaurav, I'm unable to recreate the issue you're experiencing. I've setup an ADBannerView as you've described and tried all possible configurations, devices, and simulators for it to fail on bannerViewActionDidFinish. The only thing I can suggest is deleting your ADBannerView in IB, delete your IBOutlet, clean your project (product>clean) and implement your ADBannerView again. It's very strange for some of the methods to be called and not bannerViewActionDidFinish. Is there any more code or IB settings you could include?

Comment: So I was working on helping another user and they implemented the "viewWillDisappear" method and within that method they were setting their "adBannerView.delegate = nil" which caused the "bannerViewActionDidFinish" to never be called. Do you have something similar going on?